# Rolling linear regression on large DataFrames

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have two huge dataframes `df_y` and `df_x`. 
`df_y` has columns `['date','ids','Y']`. Basically each `'ids'` has data for all the `'date'`.
`df_x` has columns `['date','X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6']`. 
`df_x` has all the `date` that are in `df_y`. However some `ids` might have shorter period, i.e., either starting from a late `date` or ending 
 at an early `date`.
I want to run a rolling linear regression (OLS) `Id ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + intercept` for each `'ids'` in `df_y` with a lookback of 200 days.

**Sample dataframes:**

```
import string, random, pandas as pd, numpy as np
ids = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(3)) for _ in range(200)]
dates = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2017-07-02')
df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'joinC':len(dates)*[2]})
df_ids = pd.DataFrame({'ids':ids, 'joinC':len(ids)*[2]})
df_values = pd.DataFrame({'Y':np.random.normal(size = 
len(dates)*len(ids))})
df_y = df_dates.merge(df_ids, on='joinC', how="outer")
df_y = df_y[['date', 'ids']].merge(df_values, left_index=True, 
right_index=True, how="inner")
df_y = df_y.sort_values(['date', 'ids'], ascending=[True, True])
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'X1':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'X2':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'X3':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'X4':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'X5':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'X6':np.random.normal(size = len(dates))})
```

**My attempt:**

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
dates = list(df_y['date'].unique())
ids = list(df_y['ids'].unique())
for i in range(200, len(dates) +1):
  for id in ids:
    s_date = dates[i - 200]
    e_date = dates[i - 1]
    Y = df_y[(df_y['date'] >= s_date) & (df_y['date'] <= e_date) & (df_y['ids'] == id)]['Y']
    Y = Y.reset_index()['Y']
    X = df_x[(df_x['date'] >= s_date) & (df_x['date'] <= e_date)]
    X = X.reset_index()[['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6']]
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    if len(X) <> len(Y):
      continue
    regr = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()  #Hangs here after 2 years.
    X_pr = X.tail(1)
    Y_hat = regr.predict(X_pr)
    Y.loc[(df_y['date'] == e_date) & (df_y['ids'] == id), 'Y_hat'] = Y_hat.tolist()[0]
```

*My attempt* above seems to be working fine up until the point where it hangs (most likely at fitting step) after running for approx. 2 years. I am inclined to use `statsmodels` since it supports regularization (planning for future work). However, if using other library makes it faster or more elegant then I am fine with it too. Could someone please help define the fastest solution that doesn't hang midway. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is a bit of a long winded question, but I wrote a [module](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pyfinance/blob/master/pyfinance/ols.py) specifically for rolling OLS with pandas.  You can do `pip install pyfinance` --> `from pyfinance.ols import PandasRollingOLS`.  It is built on NumPy, though, so you'll need to do date alignment on top of it.

Comment: Thanks @BradSolomon. Unfortunately I am not allowed to install third party  modules at work.

Comment: A first step then would be: `for id_, frame in df_y.groupby('id'):`.  This gets you pairs of (id, dataframe) where the dataframe is filtered down to that id.  You could create a dictionary of statsmodels results and add to it, with ids as keys.

Comment: Also check out [this](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pyfinance/blob/master/pyfinance/utils.py#L579) function for creating rolling windows efficiently

Comment: @BradSolomon - can you advise whether your rolling OLS can support windowed timeframes (30s, 60s, 10s etc) rather than just a number of observations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this workaround using Pandas MovingOLS

```
import pandas as pd
dates = list(df_y['date'].unique())
ids = list(df_y['ids'].unique())
Y_hats = []
for id in ids:
    Y = df_y[(df_y['ids'] == id)][['date', 'ids', 'Y']]
    Y = Y.merge(df_x, how='left', on=['date'])
    X_cols = list(df_x.columns).remove['date']
    model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=Y['Y'], x=Y[X_cols], window_type='rolling', window=250, intercept=True)
    Y['intercept'] = 1
    betas = model.beta
    betas = betas.multiply(Y[betas.columns], axis='index')
    betas = betas.sum(axis=1)
    betas = betas[betas > 0]
    betas = betas.to_frame()
    betas.columns = [['Y_hat']]
    betas = betas.merge(Y[['date', 'ids']], how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    Y_hats.append(betas)
Y_hats = pd.concat(Y_hats)
Y = Y.merge(Y_hats[['date', 'ids', 'Y_hat'], how='left', on=['date', 'ids']]
```

There is a straightforward way to use `Y['Y_hat'] = model.y_predict` if lets say one wants to fit `Y ~ X` on `(y_1, y_2, ... y_n)` and `(x_1, x_2, ... x_n)` but only wants to predict `Y_(n+1)` using `X_(n+1)`.

Comment: Those who are not interested in using Pandas MovingOLS, as it is deprecated in the later versions of Pandas, can use other implementations of MovingOLS. For example, as @BradSolomon mentioned above `pip install pyfinance --> from pyfinance.ols import PandasRollingOLS`